# Stop Dashlane auto-fill on specific input fields?

Tags: css

Does anybody know how to hint to the Dashlane browser plug-in to leave an `<input>` text field alone?

For most browser password managers, setting the `auto-complete` property to `off` works, Eg: `<input type='text' autocomplete='off' />`.

For LastPass, this additional attribute is recommended: `data-lpignore="true"`.

I have no idea what this might be for Dashlane. I have noticed that the attributes `data-kwimpalastatus="alive"` and `data-kwimpalaid="xxxx-x"` (where `xxxx-x` is an auto-generated identifier) are added to my page, so this looks like a sensible place to start, but I've not had much joy figuring out the magic incantation...

In case anyone asks, the only other browser extensions I'm using are DuckDuckGo and Google Docs offline, so it's a reasonably safe bet that the `datakwimpala*` attributes are down to Dashlane.

Does anyone have any ideas??

Thanks!

Comment: don't add the JS tag if you don't want a JS solution

Comment: What kind of input is it? A password field, or part of an adress etc?

Comment: @Sirence It's an <input> of type 'text'.  I have a variety of them for various things like first name, last name, company names, etc...  Do you think the name attribute could be a factor?

Comment: @gplumb The name could be a good point, since there must be something that maskes Dashlane think it has the appropriate data to fill the input with. Can you see what data it wants to insert?

Comment: It inserts a bunch of spans and data-kwimpala* attributes - the result of their browser extension. Without access to their source, I won't know for sure if it discriminates by name or input type (I suspect the latter since I tried using obscure name values in conjunction with autocomplete='off', to no effect). I'm sure there must be some way to tell it to skip an input when parsing forms in the DOM, but I have no idea that might be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't really provide the code you are working on, so I don't know for sure if this is you are looking for, but when I tried the following code, Dashlane didn't display its icon in the fields, and was therefore no longer able to autofill them.
I just changed the `<label>`contents: 'Name' becomes 'Enter Name', and 'Address' becomes 'Enter Address'.
I tried successfully it in Chrome, Firefox and Safari.

Let us know if this was helpful for you.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Index</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <form action="#" method="POST">
   <label>Enter Name: </label><input type="text" name="name">
   <label>Enter Address: </label><input type="text" name="address">
   <input type="submit" value="OK">
  </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Fair comment about the lack of code - I didn't think it was relevant to the question (it's a form that's not too dissimilar to what you've coded above). Did you test your page from a real server (Dashlane ignores file:/// links)?

Comment: One thing that does differ here is that you've used the <label> tag (which I haven't).  This is an interesting difference - I'll try adding this and get back to you in a few of hours :-)

Comment: I was able to test your idea a little sooner than I'd planned and the good news is it looks good :-)  It appears that Dashlane looks at the tag directly preceding the input box (in my case, it was a <span>, although it should really be a <label> like your form above) and looks for runs of text that start with "Name", "Company", etc...  Using something more verbose seems to do the trick, although this feels a little brittle - there's nothing stopping them from tweaking their parsing logic now that this is out there :-(

Comment: If anyone from Dashlane is reading this - please give us an attribute we can use!! There are many good reasons why a form might want to skip password/credential management

Comment: Yes, I tested it within a local Apache server (MAMP), since Dashlane does need a server environment to run.
Did you try to reach their support team ? I am sure they would help you with this.

Comment: I did, but they haven't been very responsive. Your approach works for now (which is better than none!) :-)  Thank you again!

Answer (score 20):

Dashlane is using the attribute data-form-type to know what type of value it should use to prefill the input.
If you set this attribute with a value "other", it will stop Dashlane from prepopulating your input fields.

See example below :

```
<input type="text" autocomplete="off" data-lpignore="true" data-form-type="other" />
```

**Note 1**: There is also the attribute "data-lpignore" for lastpass, and also "autocomplete" for the rest.

**Note 2** : The "data-form-type" attribute can be used to tell Dashlane how to pre-fill as well. There are other values you can use for this attribute like : billing, change_password, contact, forgot_password, identity, login, newsletter, other, payment, register search, shopping_basket, shipping

Comment: whats the equivalent in react?

Answer (score 11):

Daniel from Dashlane here. We recently switched our analysis engine to ML and we have a solution for you. Just add the `data-form-type` attribute with value `"other"` to any field you want us to ignore.

For more information, we released a public spec available [here](https://dashlane.github.io/SAWF/).

Comment: Is there a reason dashlane cant just respect the standard autocomplete="off" instead of  making us add yet another attribute to disable it, i swear sometimes you guys just love to make things harder for everyone.

Comment: This doesn't work (anymore). Chrome plugin v6.2224.0.

Comment: Works on Version 6.2224.4

Answer (score 4):

tl;dr disabling autofill on specific input fields is not supported and not currently on their roadmap.

I spoke to Dashlane's Support just now, here is a shortened summary:

> **ME**: I'm looking for information on how to disable Dashlane
> autocomplete for specific form fields, but couldn't find anything at
> https://support.dashlane.com/. I've created an example here to
> demonstrate and would welcome any help.
>
> **DASHLANE**: Right now we can only stop Dashlane for a specific page or
> website never for specific fields
>
> **ME**: do you know if there are any plans to allow Developers to disable
> autofill for specific fields? My real example is a postcode/zip code
> field which has its own autocomplete which lists addresses which match
> the postcode you entered - and the dashlane autofill dialog appearing
> over the top of it presents a problem to users of our sites.
>
> **DASHLANE**: I understand how this may affect your Users I'm so sorry,
> for now, we don't have it on our roadmap, But I will be sharing your
> feedback with our Product Team, who are always looking to integrate
> our users' input into their plans for upcoming updates to Dashlane.
>
> **ME**: Are there any JavaScript variables or other
> changes to the webpage we can look for, so that we could disable our
> own autocomplete feature for dashlane users? so they're not presented
> with 2 which clash? We'd use that information to turn ours off, so the
> only one in use would be Dashlane's, which can't be disabled.
>
> **DASHLANE**: We don't have a "blueprint" of the code in order to provide
> any JavaScript code
>
> **ME**: If some kind of attribute (ideally
> autocomplete="off" which seems to be the standard) could be supported
> it would be a huge help, this is a cause of abandonment in our
> checkout process and I'm sure it must affect other websites as well as
> ours. Thanks for your time.
>
> **DASHLANE**: Let's hope this can be a reality in the future

The example I mentioned is reproduced here:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Disabling Dashlane Form AutoComplete?</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Disabling Dashlane Form AutoComplete?</h1>
    <p>
      As a web developer, how can I instruct Dashlane not to display a prompt to
      autocomplete a particular form field?
    </p>
    <p>
      In this example, the Last Name field has
      <code>autocomplete="off"</code> but DashLane still displays an autofill
      dialog when you focus on that element.
    </p>
    <p>
      Thanks
    </p>
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Example Form</legend>
      <form action="https://output.jsbin.com/setopoyawi" method="GET">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <label>
              First Name
              <input name="first-name" type="text" autocomplete="given-name" />
            </label>
          </li>
          <li>
            <label>
              Last Name
              <input name="last-name" type="text" autocomplete="off" />
            </label>
          </li>
          <li>
            <label>
              Password
              <input
                name="password"
                type="password"
                autocomplete="new-password"
              />
            </label>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </fieldset>
    <h2>References</h2>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a
          href="https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/autocomplete"
          >https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/autocomplete</a
        >
      </li>
      <li>
        <a
          href="https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion"
          >https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion</a
        >
      </li>
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem with a searchable react-select component which stalled (!) the browser when leaving the field. I could only get rid of the grey Dashlane icon in the input field by moving the following button to the left of the input field (it was in the same row right of the input field before). It seems that they identify relevant input fields by checking if there is a button to the right in the same row. I observed that if the button is not to the right of the input field but in the next row, the Dashlane icon also does not appear.

Comment: Hi. I'm curious, what do you mean by "move away"?  Do you mean in terms of screen real-estate, outside of a <form> element or just putting other things in the DOM between a text and it's submit button?

Comment: Hi, I clarified my answer. Since it is not good from a design standpoint to have the "Get stats" button in my case on the left, I also sent an email to Dashlane, I will post the answer here.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like dashlane tracks the name and the placeholder property of the input, but not the label as far as i know.

Changing the name of the input to something Dashlane would not be able to recognize helped. So instead of "country" i changed it to "cnt", which solved the problem.

Although, if you need to really add these keywords in the placeholder, you might need to get creative.
Making a custom input where placeholder is empty and add a "fake placeholder" on top could be the way?